# Instance in another document doesn't recognize variables

Tags: python, tkinter, instances

```
class window:
    def __init__(self):

        addMovie = Tk()
        addMovie.minsize(300, 150)
        addMovie.maxsize(300, 150)

        self.premier = IntVar()

        isPremier = Checkbutton(self.addMovie, text="Premier", variable=self.premier)
        isPremier.place(relx=0, x=5, y=40)

    def detect(self):
        if self.premier.get() == 1:
            print("Premier")
        else:
            print("Not premier")
```

So this code works perfectly if I create the instance in the same file, but when I try to make the instance from another place, for example newWindow = GUI.newMovie.window() only the checkbuttons are not working properly, other elements as Entry and ttk.ComboBox does work as intend

Im calling the detect method from a button, if that info is needed

Comment: Does your "another place" also create a Tkinter main window? A Tkinter program should only have one main window, otherwise Bad Things happen.

Comment: Yeah it have another main window, since I didn't found something like an internal window or frame or something for tkinter (I'm starting to learn tkinter for educational purpose), and since that worked perfectly for other widgets I didn't think about getting an error cause of that

Comment: Take a look at [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm)

Comment: Toplevel worked perfectly, thank you!